# FileZilla does not open connection, Putty does

Tags: ssh, ftp, putty, filezilla

This could be a silly question.

I'm getting an error when connecting to a server through filezilla.

Connected to domainx.corp.pre.corp Error: Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server Error: Could not connect to server

When connecting with putty through ssh it works fine.

I would like a GUI interface, to avoid using command line. Could you help me?

Comment: Did you [select SFTP as the Protocol in Site Manager](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ooTe9.jpg)?

Comment: You should check server-side log to see why it closes the SFTP connection. Or even better, contact the server administrator.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS & W7 using Filezilla trying to connect to AWS EC2 Linux (Amazon std AMI) had this problem for ages till did this (on AWS):

1-install vsftpd by doing: yum install vsfptd

2-edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config so that the sftp line reads: Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

3-restart the ssh service: service ssh restart

Should work now.

Of course this all assumes that you have done the dance to set up ssh keys etc.

Clearly, you will need root priviledges to do all the above.

If you mess up sshd_config you may well end up locked out of the Linux instance, so do all this wearing you [big mexican hat](https://www.bnj.com/blog/cowboy-coding-pink-sombrero/)